# VScode stops suggesting classes and functions when debugging (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, autosuggest

When I start debugging my app in VS code it's everything ok, but the editor just stops suggesting classes (Widgets, of course, included), auto-import, import suggestions and functions. I don't have this problem in another project I'm working with, so I think it could be due to a wrong setting, but I don't know how to copy my settings from one project to another one. Could you help me with this?

Comment: try to run `Dart : Restart Analysis Server ` in vs code command pallet

Comment: @GJJ2019 Awesome! It worked as a workaround because the best would be not needing to do that, but definitely, your comment helped me so much!

Answer (score 2):

try to run `Dart : Restart Analysis Server`  in vs code command pallet

Comment: It fixed de issue but I still would like to avoid this situation. Any idea?

Comment: try to use `Dart: Preview Lsp`